# How to Display an Error Page when the SQL Server is Down?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

My company has an OLD webpage that was created in ASP.NET many years ago. I have never worked with ASP.NET and I'm really confused as to how I can display an error when the database is down. The web site gets information from textboxes using HMTL and asp and stores it on the database. The connection info is on a web.config file. How would I go about not showing a certain asp page if the database does not respond, and instead show an error message?

Can anyone guide me down the right path?

I've worked with a little PHP, JavaScript, Jquery, MySQL. However this is all new to me.

Also, this is a temporary fix while I revamp the webpage, but we MUST show something so the clients know it is not functioning correctly. So I'm under a lot of pressure to fix it and I'm clueless.

Comment: Are you using Classic ASP or ASP.net.  I'd guess it's .net if your conn string is in web.config

Comment: Yeah probably .NET... How could I see which one it is?

Comment: What are your file extensions.  .asp is for classic, .aspx is for .net

Comment: I'm rather less of an expert with .net than I am with classic, but you should usually get a .net error page (often known as a YSOD or Yellow Screen of Death) which tells you that it couldn't connect.  At a guess you could have something in your code which triggers a response redirect when an error occurs.  You probably need to post some code before anyone can give you any more advice.

Comment: What happens now if the database is down?

Comment: And is the DATABASE DOWN event planned or is it that the connection is not stable and it goes down.

Answer (score 0):

In your Master Page (If you have one, otherwise in each individual page) Page_Load method, add...

```
if(!DatabaseConnectivity.IsDatabaseUp())
{
   Response.Redirect("~/DatabaseDown.aspx");
}
```

Add a DatabaseConnectivity.cs class to your App_Code folder. Add a function called IsDatabaseUp() to this class. In that function, do a simple query to your database. If you get an exception you can assume the database is down and return false.

```
public class DatabaseConnectivity
{
   public static bool IsDatabaseUp()
   {
      try
      {
         SqlDataSource ds=new SqlDataSource();
         ds.ConnectionString=System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCONNSTRINGNAME"].ToString();
         ds.SelectCommand="select count(*) from sys.Tables";
         ds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
         return true;
      }
      catch(Exception)
       {
          return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Add a DatabaseDown.aspx file to the root of your site with a notification that the site is down.

Comment: This looks about right, thank you! Would you suggest a simple select statement for the query? Also how do I connect if the connection info is in the web.config file? Like, what would be an example of the syntax?

Comment: I'm not going to presume to know what database you're using so I can't tell you the code to do that. But I suggest you look at the rest of the application and see how it's handling database interaction, that should give you a good idea of how to get the connection info.

If it was an Oracle database, I'd use something like `select 1 from dual` but if it was SQL Server I'd do something like `select * from sys.Tables` (but I'm not a regular SQL Server user so there may be something more robust I don't know about)

Comment: @jlaverde I saw in the question title you're using SQL Server, so I've updated my code showing you how to perform the query. Keep in mind, I'm one of the few people that uses SqlDataSource from code behind regularly.

Comment: -1: Why use `SqlDataSource` and not just `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`? Also, you should only be catching `SqlException` and such. If there's a "world is coming to an end exception" thrown, then returning `false` isn't quite good enough.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Because I like SqlDataSource, it is much cleaner in code. The only exception that should be happening from that code is if there's a problem communicating with the database. In any case, the code is a demonstrative example of what way you could implement what he wants. It's just to get him started, it's not necessarily what he has to put in production. Feel free to write your own response if you think that my solution wasn't enough to get him started.

Comment: It's not just about "him". It's about all the other "hims" and "hers" who will ready your answer in years to come. Many will simply copy and paste your answer without realizing that you were only providing a "starter" answer, and not a permanent, best, answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not going to write an entire program for him, or for anyone. Anybody that comes along can obviously see what's going on. Like I said, if you feel it's necessary then feel free to write your own response.